# Play RTMP Stream from RED5 server on a webpage

Tags: video-streaming, red5, mediaelement.js

How to play RTMP  video stream from RED5 server on a html webpage using videojs / mediaelementjs ? 
Could anyone please give me an example (What settings are to be made so that the player can play the stream) ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know mediaelementjs does not support any variant of the rtmp protocol; this is your first hurdle. Your only option is non-streaming if you're going to use Red5 with this library.

Comment: Thanks for the information Mondain. As I am new to this, Currently I know only JWPLayer and FlowPlayer which could play streams from the RTMP video streaming sources. Could anybody please suggest some more players which are capable of playing RTMP streams? Any information would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: If your intention is to play a media file for HTML5 clients, you should start with a different server. Red5 is for flash based media clients.